# private_pub gem rails and https error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, thin, private-pub

I've been using private_pub in production for over a year now and recently I've just moved the app from http to https. We have a signed cert already installed and everything else is working within the application but I'm getting the following error when I private_pub/thin submits anything to be pushed.

```
SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

I have been unable to find anything specifically with this error and private_pub/thin but other issues I've seen have been in relation to sunspot/solr pointing to *localhost* when it needs *127.0.0.1*. My private_pub configs are using the actual https://domain.com.

My app is able to connect to faye.js but I'm getting the server error above.

private_pub_thin.yml:

```
---
port: 4443
ssl: true
ssl_key_file: /path/to/ssl.key
ssl_cert_file: /path/to/ssl.cert
environment: production
rackup: private_pub.ru
daemonize: true
```

private_pub.yml:

```
production:
server: "https://sub.mydomain.com:4443/faye"
secret_token: "<token here>"
signature_expiration: 3600 # one hour
```

private_pub.ru:

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "yaml"
require "faye"
require "private_pub"

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

PrivatePub.load_config(File.expand_path("../config/private_pub.yml", __FILE__), ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development")
run PrivatePub.faye_app
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

--- edit ---

I didn't mention this, but I do have the port 4443 opened up on the server's iptables and I even tried turning off iptables altogether for testing. Still got the same error

Comment: I'm starting to think the actual issue is post/put via ajax calls... I'm not finding others who are having this problem.I just added these configs in hopes it would help, but it did not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130964/rails-3-2-11-ssl-configuration

Comment: It may seem silly (but I don't know you, so maybe it's not), but have you tried running in a different environment to eliminate the possibility of it being your environment causing the issue?  I am not intimately familiar with your problem, but it smells like there may be something else going on here beyond your actual application.  The fact that there has been no other discussion encourages me to post this in hopes it gets some sort of discussion going. . .  maybe nudge something in the right direction.  If this is open source I'd be willing to try to run it locally if you direct me to do so.

Comment: I somehow missed the fact that this was in production (sorry).  I understand that this makes running it in a different environment almost pointless (apart from simply troubleshooting on a really high level).  I'll leave this here so you have time to see it, but will probably delete the comments in a while since they likely provide almost no assistance.  I'm sorry, seems like an annoying problem.

Comment: I too faced the same issues, have written anwer in the below link, please verify, this might help!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/54073210/10878745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out... It was all to do with the SSL certs.

It appears I was missing the CA Bundle or it just wasn't installed correctly. Fixing this and then following this fix here: [Using private_pub with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476428/using-private-pub-with-ssl)

appending the ca_bundle to the actual cert worked.

Also some useful tools I found to help debug:

https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools/tree/8b3dec4bedcc725a142fa9bc297610f8d09f5d9d
https://www.digicert.com/help/

Hope it helps others.